# How do i know if user has received the push notification sent from privatepub gem

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, sockets, private-pub, socketrocket

Can any one tell me the solution related to PrivatePub. Well i am using privatepub gem for push notification to ios app. I wanted to know is it possible to get any kind of response which states that the particular user has received the notification and particular user has not received the notification. If yes please post the code with your answer, I am publishing the notification through controller.

Answer (score 1):

The APNS does not provide any mechanism for delivery reports. You can perform some callback to your server from the iOS app to indicate a user has action the notification, but that excludes delivery without action